# Writing a copy constructor for a class in C++ that has a set containing pointers

Tags: c++, class, object, copy-constructor

Say you had a class in C++ like below:

```
template<typename T>
class my_class {
public:
private:
  std::set<T*> class_set;
  int elements_in_set;
}
```

I'm trying to write a copy constructor for this class, and so far I'm stuck at the following, where I only know how to copy over the integer `elements_in_set`, but I'm not sure how to copy over the set, and do a deep copy of the things that other's `class_set`'s pointers are pointing to:

```
my_class(my_class const& other)
: class_set{}, elements_in_set{other.elements_in_set} {
  //don't know how to copy over the set
}
```

I know that if the class has a pointer as a member, you'd use `new data type[size of data pointer points to]`, but do you have to call `new` to make the set itself, and then `new` for every pointer in the set? Any help would be greatly appreciated. It would also be nice if there was a way to do this using standard library algorithms rather than `for` loops.

Comment: No, you should not use `new` to make the new set. Yes, you must use `new` to create every pointer that goes into the new set. Don't attempt to do this with a standard algorithm until you can do it with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. Do you want a shallow or a deep copy?

For a shallow copy (both instances of my_class sharing the same T objects) just copy the set in the same way as the int member.

For a deep copy (the new instances gets its own copy of the T objects) you need to run through the original set, create a new T and insert it into the new set. If it is just T objects in the set using new will do the job. If T is a base-class you will have to add a clone function.

Note that having a pointer in a set is at least slightly unusual. If you want the second behaviour (deep copy) using values instead of pointers would give you that for free.

Edit: Note that your int member is redundant. A set keeps track of its size.

Comment: If `T` is a base-class, then using values instead of pointers would give you [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).